# Не получается подключить файл с помощью cmake. fatal error: Нет такого файла или каталога

Tags: c++, cmake, build

cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.4.0 )

project(network)

set(SOURCE_LIB
        src/Client/client.cpp
        src/Server/server.cpp
        src/network.cpp)

set(HEADER_LIB
        include/Client/client.h
        include/Server/server.h
        include/network.h
        ../include/logger.h) #проблема тут

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE_LIB} ${HEADER_LIB})
```

подключаю вот так:

```
#include "include/logger.h"
```

Ошибка, хотя ide не подчеркивает ничего, только при сборке пишет что не может найти:
In file included from

```
/home/user/CLionProjects/net/src/Server/server.cpp:5:
/home/user/CLionProjects/net/include/Server/server.h:22:10: fatal error: include/logger.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
   22 | #include "include/logger.h"
```

иерархия папок:
[image: иерархия]

Comment: `#include ""` (при обычном использовании) требует пути относительно этого файла

Comment: @user7860670 не совсем понимаю что мне в таком случае нужно сделать

Comment: Нужно указать правильный путь в инклюде.

Comment: @user7860670 не понимаю... я перепробовал:
`../include/logger.h`
`../logger.h`
`logger.h`
`include/logger.h`
ну это же верные пути, что не так, я явно чего-то не понимаю

Comment: а этот logger.h находится "вне каталога с исходниками"?

Comment: @lbsmart ¿Эм, а вы знаете, что такое "относительный путь"? Кроме того, в папку с именем "include" обычно добавляют файлы, которые включаются через `#include <>`. Чтобы это работало также следует добавить соотв. директиву для компилятора с указанием include папки (target_include_directories в cmake)

Comment: @KoVadim скрин полной иерархии прикрепил, я пытаюсь изменить cmake папки netlib, а логгер находится вне папки netlib, он в самом проекте там где лежит основной cmake, там вроде на скрине все видно :)

Comment: @user7860670 нет

Comment: @lbsmart с помощью `include_directories("тут путь к logger/include")` добавляете путь к своему файлу logger.h. И потом в main.cpp или где нужно, добавляете его как `#include <logger.h>`.  В `set(HEADER_LIB` его уже не нужно добавлять

Comment: @user7860670 инзначально не знал что это связанно с "относительным путем", так бы конечно посмотрел:)

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо помогло!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш файл logger.h находится "вне каталога исходников" (то есть, не в том каталоге, где находится CMakeLists.txt или подкаталогах этого каталога). А это значит, что его нужно подключать по другому.

Вначале нужно указать CMake, где искать этот файл

```
include_directories("тут путь к logger/include")
```

в список HEADER_LIB такой файл не нужно добавлять.

И теперь можно этот файл использовать как "обычный библиотечный"

```
#include <logger.h>
```

А вот есть у этого logger.h есть cpp файл, то все будет немного сложнее.